# Remove column from Excel export

Tags: excel, crystal-reports

In Crystal Reports 2008, I can see there are 14 columns in the report (column titles are in the Page Header) but, when I do an Excel Export (Microsoft Excel (97-2003) Data-Only), there are 51 columns. All 14 columns I can see in Crystal Reports are included.

But, I cannot see where all the additional columns in the Excel are being specified in Crystal.

I need to remove one of the columns in the Excel Export as it is not required.

I removed the view, which is used for this column, from Database Expert. But, the column heading still appears in the Excel Export. Once the view was removed, the data becomes mismatched.

Comment: are you able to see the data for those additional columns?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove the column by deleting it from "Report Explorer".

All the columns were being used in the Page Header, they just weren't all visible.

By switching from Field Explorer to Report Explorer (bottom right corner) I was able to view and delete any of the additional columns in the Excel.